# is there a way to read .dat files as in the storage format for bitcoin blocks?

Tags: json, database, encoding, bitcoin, blockchain

I've generated some "raw data" that is encoded as `.dat`from my bitcoin testnet, accordingly I have the file [/blk00000.dat](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/docker_test/blob/master/blk00000.dat), is this the data of my blocks I've generated? i.e. the transaction data etc.?

It looks like this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 00ff ffff ff03 5301
01ff ffff ff01 00f2 052a 0100 0000 2321
02f6 89e4 8543 5d1a 78f9 d08c a612 7e36
2216 20e1 ad70 7576 dbae 41e7 c01d 406a
b7ac 0000 0000 fabf b5da b300 0000 0000
0020 abb4 1583 7333 ff2b fcde f019 f2ad
4f4d 5c69 462f 277e 1c52 8564 53c2 ab2d
7674 1c8d de8d e0fa 11eb 9dfe 798d 4839
5a61 b9d3 439c f4e7 79a5 ebe3 dabe f15d
2930 d791 7357 ffff 7f20 0100 0000 0101
0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 ffff ffff 0354 0101 ffff ffff
0100 f205 2a01 0000 0023 2102 f689 e485
435d 1a78 f9d0 8ca6 127e 3622 1620 e1ad
7075 76db ae41 e7c0 1d40 6ab7 ac00 0000
00fa bfb5 dab3 0000 0000 0000 2026 a3de
12ea 2f3a deb5 10bf d337 4390 7371 c2d6
```

is there a way to render it as human readable JSON, so I can see it as something like this:

```
{
    "version" : 90300,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 0,
    "timeoffset" : 0,
    "connections" : 1,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 0.00000000,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1413617762,
    "keypoolsize" : 101,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00001000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I have 2 `bitcoin.conf` files, as I have two nodes, they look like this:

```
# testnet-box functionality
regtest=1
dnsseed=0
upnp=0

# listen on different ports than default testnet
port=19000
rpcport=19001

# always run a server, even with bitcoin-qt
server=1

# enable SSL for RPC server
#rpcssl=1

rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0

rpcuser=admin1
rpcpassword=123
```

It should be noted that I'm using the configuration that I got from [here](https://github.com/freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box)

---

**EDIT II**

I had a problem with the last step, namely XXX

it resulted in the following error:

[image]

if I had to guess I would say I went wrong on this part

`<path-to-datadirectory>` where exactlly should that be? where `blk00000.dat` lives? the whole directory? or exactly that file?

Comment: you may use any parser for *.dat files, for example my parser https://github.com/ragestack/blockchain-parser

Answer (score 4):

Ok your comment made this more clear to me what you need. Here is a totally different approach, thus I'm creating a separate answer.

What you want is a block explorer! You can very easy attach [insight](https://github.com/bitpay/insight-ui) to your testnet node.

#### Index transactions on your node

First thing you have to do is to restart your testnet node with indexing enabled. `txindex`, `addressindex`, `timestampindex` and `spentindex` needs to be set to true in your `bitcoin.conf`.

Add `reindex=1` to your `bitcoin.conf`. After you start Bitcoin once with `reindex=1` you should remove it, otherwise it will reindex every time the node starts. Be sure to leave the other indexes, though.

#### Install bitcore

Install [bitcore-node](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-node) via NodeJS.

```
npm install -g bitcore-node
bitcore-node create -d <path-to-datadirectory> testnode
cd testnode
```

#### Install insight API and UI

Inside your `testnode` working directory, add insight:

```
bitcore-node install insight-api
bitcore-node install insight-ui
bitcore-node start
```

#### Inspect your blockchain

Open a web browser to `http://localhost:3001/insight/` to access the Block explorer.

The [API endpoints](https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api#api-http-endpoints) will be available by default at: `http://localhost:3001/insight-api/block-index/0` (example to get the genesis block). The API returns JSON:

```
{
  "blockHash":"000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f"
}
```

The blockhash you can use to get block details, like `http://localhost:3001/insight-api/block/000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f`.

Comment: I posted the contents of my `bitcoin.conf` in the **EDIT** component of the original question that I just added

Comment: is [this conf file](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/bitcoin-dev-box/blob/master/hometester/testnet/1/bitcoin.conf) right? is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yeah looks good. Try to reindex it now, maybe if you have important contents, make a backup of your testnet chain.

Comment: at the risk of making a fool of myself, where would `<path-to-datadirectory> ` be?

Comment: is that where `/blk00000.dat` lives?

Comment: so that maybe it looks something like `bitcore-node create -d /home/matthias/lab/bitcoin-testnet-box/1/regtest/blocks testnode
`

Comment: hmm- something went wrong- I put the issue in the original question under **EDIT II**

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with an interesting comment from another thread here:

> The data is stored in an application-specific format optimized for compact storage, and wasn't really intended to be easily parsed by other applications. You can access the data in the chainstate through the gettxout RPC call, and the data in the block index through getblock. I'll try to find time for a write-up of the exact format. – [Pieter Wuille Jul 29 '13 at 7:17](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10814/6441)

However, if you are still interested in getting this done, the blockchain is stored in two [levelDB](http://leveldb.org/) databases: one for the blocks and one for the chainstate. There are multiple ways to open that, I would recommend to look into [libbitcoin](http://libbitcoin.dyne.org/doc/blockchain.html), or bitcoin-leveldb:

```
// Define a threadpool with 1 thread.
threadpool pool(1);
// Create a LevelDB blockchain.
leveldb_blockchain ldb_chain(pool);
// Initialize our global 'chain' pointer from above.
chain = &ldb_chain;
// Start the database using its implementation specific method.
ldb_chain.start("../database", blockchain_started);
```

The Bitcoin fork of levelDB used in Bitcoin core contains [some documentation on how to read and access the data](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/leveldb/blob/bitcoin-fork/doc/table_format.txt).

There is also [an excellent thread on Bitcoin Stack Exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/29418/6441) which tells you about the key:value model structure of the database, which is required if you try to access the database manually.

Comment: really what I want to do it to inspect the data that I have created on a local personal testnet that I have configured with just two nodes

Answer (score 0):

There is a [blckdat-stream](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/blkdat-stream) project from the wonderful people that make bitcoinjs-lib.

You need to use it together with bitcoinjs-lib; blckdat-stream only "parses" the dat files in that it chunks them into separate blocks. You need to parse the blocks themselves by bitcoinjs-lib itself.